# Multiple page use div throws Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have this dialog being used on two separate pages. Page1.aspx and Page2.aspx. Both pages use the master page which is where the div is at. The js code is its own file. Everything Works fine on Page1.aspx but for some reason on Page2.aspx, when I click the button this happens. Also, on Page2.aspx, the text area for some unknown reason shows up on the page (this should only appear in the popup div when the specified button is clicked), so there is something happening that I am not able to figure out.

**Error:**

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'open'
    at Function.error (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:253:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:246:16)
    at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:370:19)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:137:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as dialog] (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js:236:10)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://23.97.29.252/webapp/js/CommentModal.js:47:29)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:5226:27)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js:4878:28)
```

**Div HTML Code:**

```
<div id="commentDialog" title="Comment">
    <textarea id="commentTextArea" style="resize: none" rows="8" cols="42" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#commentDialog').dialog({
        'buttons': {
            'Save': {
                id: 'commentSave',
                text: 'Save',
                click: function() {
                    //Save to DB with Web API
                }
            },
            'Edit': {
                id: 'commentEdit',
                text: 'Edit',
                click: function ()
                {
                    $('textarea#commentTextArea').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#commentEdit').hide();
                    $('#commentSave').show();
                }
            },
            'Cancel': {
                text: 'Cancel',
                click: function ()
                {
                    $('#commentEdit').show();
                    $('#commentSave').hide();
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        },
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
    });

    $('button#commentSave').hide();

    $('[id^=CommentButton]').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#commentDialog").dialog("open");
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you link to the page that doesn't work? What you have seems to work fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xqKMZR

Comment: @MichaelCoker The website isn't live so I don't have a link for you. I'm guessing this has something to do with sharing the JS file between two aspx pages which the link you provided doesn't really mimic that.

I can get the popup to work for Page1.aspx but not Page2.aspx.

Comment: if they're separate pages, I don't see why sharing it between the two would just affect 1 page but not the other... but yeah not sure what to tell you if we can't see it. I'm assuming you don't have any other meaningful errors or output in the browser console?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I updated the error to reflect exactly what I see.

Comment: It seems to me like the first `$('#commentDialog').dialog({ ... });` (with `autoOpen`, `height`, `width`, etc) isn't being read, or there is an error or something. You're sure that's on the page and it isn't erroring? Assuming that looks OK, what if you copy and paste all of that into the browser console on that page, then copy and paste the `$('[id^=CommentButton]').click(...)` block into the console? Will it fire then?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Copying everything to the console like you said works. Also, If I put the div on both aspx pages instead of the master page it works also. For some reason this way I'm getting this issue but I want to obviously avoid having the same code twice (even if it is html).

Comment: @MichaelCoker So, including the script of the JS of the dialog on Page2.aspx fixed the problem. It seems weird that Page1.aspx doesn't need the script included but Page2.aspx does. Any idea? Feel free to provide an answer so I can mark yours as best.

Comment: Sweet! What's in the script you're including - this JS you've pasted into your post?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Yes. page1.aspx doesn't seem to need it so just Page2.aspx and the Master page have it included.. weird.

Comment: That is weird... I'm assuming it's being included somehow, otherwise how would it know what your options are, what elements to assign the click handler to and fire the modal, etc? Are you sure it isn't being included somehow via an include file or something? I'm not even sure what to put in an answer on here for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You must create the dialog first. Try:

```
$("#commentDialog").dialog().open();
```

Comment: Doing this doesn't help. It causes the dialog on Page1.aspx to not work and on Page2.aspx it is a broken popup dialog.